# Resize an image according to smaller dimension using CSS

Tags: css, image, dynamic

Users are able to upload an image that get displayed in a square container in the UI. The problem is that they can upload images of any size so they may be to small, portrait, landscape or some odd aspect ratio. Images should always fill the container and be centralli positioned.

I would like to style these images so that smaller dimension is always of specified size while keeping aspect ratio as is.

Suppose I want my images to have resulting dimension 50px (smaller one should):

- **Portrait image**: 100px(w) x 200px(h) => result: 50x100
- **Landscape image**: 200px(w) x 100px(h) => result: 100x50
- **Square image**: 100px(w) x 100px(h) => result: 50x50

I want my images to be **at least** 50px in either dimension. Using `max-width` and `max-height` resizes images to *at most* 50px...

### Requirements for *original solution*

1. CSS only
2. Images should be IMG tags, and **not placed** as backgrounds
3. No Javascript

I've tried using max-*dimension* styles but using this I can always control just one dimension. I want to control both simultaneously.

### Requirements for *plan B solution*

It's possible that *original solution* restricts too much with its requirements. In this case I would be using CSS backgrounds as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24121770/75642). The problem is that my images aren't defined during design time, but rather during runtime as users are selecting images and I'm using FileAPI to display them before uploading to server. This would require me to define inline styles and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you use FileAPI to display them before uploading, why not to use JavaScript to determine the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @hashemqolami well in that case why not just crop and resize it in javascript and display result that will always have correct size and aspect ratio...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resulting solution

Unfortunately **it isn't possible to resize images directly using only CSS**. And with images I mean the `IMG` elements. This functionality is otherwise supported for element background images. And `IMG` elements are no different in this regard so we can actually set backgrounds on them too. My image therefore displays a transparent image and has a background set to what image should display.

#### This is the solution I ended up using:

```
img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I'm programmatically setting background image using inline CSS as images are read using FileAPI from local file system and I'm using *data URI* to set them as backgrounds.

Works...

Answer (score -1):

try this css for image tag:

```
img{
 max-width: 100px;
 max-height: 100px;
}
```

in this case you have Portrait and Landscape  images as you want(with keeping their aspect ratio).but only Square are stayed 100*100.
[here is a fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Shirin_Abdolahi/L22ztgvc/) .

Comment: This is resized to larger of both dimensions. I want to resize to smaller of the dimensions. So the image would be **at least** 50px wide or high. and not **at most** as you've done.

Comment: you said you want to resize 100*200 image to 50*100 and so on.it means getting image "smaller" not larger.and if you want minimum size to you simply can add min-width and min-height as well.

Comment: No you apparently misunderstood my question. Yes my images will become smaller, but my square is 50 by 50 and not 100 as you've set it. My numbers were just an example. One could upload an image 1000x75... 75 in this case should become 50. And if I've set min-width and height it wouldn't preserve aspect ratio.

Comment: you want to have the aspect ratio and have image 50*50 at the same time?

Comment: do you want your smaller image to became larger too or not ?

Comment: Aspect ratio has to be preserved in order for the image to not get distorted. It will then be cropped by container to square size. Got it? Yes smaller images should be enlarged.

Comment: oh,now I get it. I don't think there is a way with only css.At least I don't know .sry !